# Issues Building A Polygon with Geolocated Data

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gis, polygon

I am having issues building a polygon in BigQuery with already geo-located data. When I use the below query to build it based on my reading of other questions posted on this matter I get this error that I have not been able to troubleshoot after reading many other questions related to this matter. Would I be able to get assistance with this? I have posted the data I am using as a pandas data frame to give you all a proper reference point.

Error message:

ST_MakePolygon failed: Invalid polygon loop: Edge 1 has duplicate vertex with edge 7

Query:

```
WITH Table as (SELECT DISTINCT location, latitude, longitude FROM dataset.table 
WHERE latitude is not null and longitude is not null)

SELECT County, PRECINCT_NAME, ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_MAKELINE(ARRAY_AGG(ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude, latitude)))) as geom
FROM Table
Group By location
```

dataset for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[('location', 'location', 'location', 'location', 'location', 'location'), (-84.2996966, -84.31496, -84.31463, -84.29973, -84.29918, -84.29949), 
(39.1699112, 39.219543, 39.21876, 39.16986, 39.17092, 39.17686)], columns=['location', 'longitude', 'latitude'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of failing

```
ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_MAKELINE(ARRAY_AGG(ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude, latitude)))) as geom
```

you can try below

```
ST_CONVEXHULL(ST_UNION_AGG(ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude, latitude))) as geom
```

If to run this for sample data in  your question - result is

```
POLYGON((-84.31496 39.219543, -84.29973 39.16986, -84.2996966 39.1699112, -84.29918 39.17092, -84.29949 39.17686, -84.31463 39.21876, -84.31496 39.219543))
```

[image]